# Is it possible to Transfer from one google cloud server data to another?

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

Can anyone clarify my doubt?

My android app saves users information in a google cloud from my app. Recently i changed my server and created another google cloud with another mail id. 
Now i wanted to fetch users already saved data from old server to be shown in new server. Is it possible???

Comment: Unless google offers the option you may need a proffesional solution to sync data between 2 cloud drives such as this one https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-backup-google-drive-to-another-google-drive/  -- check the google-cloud-storage if they offer a free solution

Comment: Is your app saving data in Drive or Google Cloud Storage? (These are two different services.)
If it's saving in GCS you can write an app that copies in the cloud (without downloading): https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite

Comment: i am saving it in google cloud storage in the form of tables